# Get multiple connectionStrings from Web.Config to a dictonary c# without loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, dictionary

In my MVC application I have 3 connection strings in my web.config - connection string section.
Without loop I want to get all the connection strings specified in the config to a
dictionary<string, string>.
I have tried below using loop.

```
 foreach (var item in Environments)
{
 connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["[string.Format("ConnectionString_{0}",item )].ToString();
 Dictionary.add(item , connString );                  
}

------------ IN Web.config

<configuration>
<connectionStrings>

 <add name="ConnectionString_Dev" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyy;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 <add name="ConnectionString_PreProd" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyy;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  
 <add name="ConnectionString_PreStage" connectionString="Data Source=xxxxxxxx;Initial Catalog=yyyy;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 

</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: LINQ uses loops internally, so please don't be in an assumption that linq's are without loops

Comment: I'm genuinely curious where the "without loop" constraint comes from. It shows up as an arbitrary requirement on questions so often. Is there someone out there teaching loops are bad for performance or something like that? Point is, if you have a collection of some sort, you will have to iterate over it. If you don't, or if you call methods that hide it, in the end the CPU is still iteratively executing instructions to handle each collection element. So please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Environments` implements `IEnumerable<string>`,
and `Dictiorary` is `Dictioary<string, string>` -
A linq based solution would be something like this:

```
Environments.ToDictionary(
    k => k, 
    v => ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[$"ConnectionString_{v}"].ToString()
);
```

Please note that `ToDictionary`, just like most (if not all) other linq methods, uses `forech` internally - so it's not really "without loops".

Answer (score -1):

You can do this

```
Dictionary<string, string> dCs = new Dictionary<string, string>();

var allConnectionStrings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings;
foreach(ConnectionStringSettings cs in allConnectionStrings)
{
   dCs.Add(cs.Name, cs.ConnectionString);
}
```